# Positioning text over an image so that it always points to the same spot in the image even when resizing the browser

Tags: css, image, position

I am currently building a website with weblflow but run into a problem that someone here might be able to help me with. The is an issue I have for multiple projects, so I would really appreciate someone's help.

Basically, if you have an image full screen size (set as background image, 100vw and 100vh), and then want to put headings/labels on top of that image pointing to specific sections in that image, how do I get these headings/labels always move with the image when someone would resize the browser?

As for now I used absolute positioning for the headings/labels and used % margins to position them where I want them to point to on the image. The image itself I have set to position relative. However, with that solution the headings/labels never exactly continue to point to the same spot on the image when resizing the browser.

I think the main issue is that when someone only changes the browser's width, the image gets (for example) smaller bc it keeps it's ratio. Vertically the headings/labels don't move bc the height was unchanged, it's just the browser's width that was changed. So horizontally it's still fine but vertically the headings are off now since the image got smaller due to resizing the browser's width. So I guess I do know why it's not working but I don't know how to fix this. If someone has a solution for this, please let me know.

As an example: if you open this page: http://nestin.bold-themes.com/classy/ and scroll down to the section ‘True value is always inside’, there is an image with 5 numbered labels, no matter how you resize the browser, these labels/numbers stay in the same spot of the image. I see this quite often on websites. How was this achieved?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a parent wrapper, put inside the image and all the divs.
the parent is relateive and the divs are absolute.

here's a small demo.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.parent .box {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(1.6vw + 10px); height: calc(1.6vw + 10px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
.parent .box.window {
  top: 0;
  left: 39%;
}
.parent .box.light {
  top: 16%;
  left: 46%;
}
.parent .box.pool {
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
}
.parent .box.plant {
  top: 55%;
  left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box plant">1</div>
  <div class="box window">2</div>
  <div class="box light">3</div>
  <div class="box pool">4</div><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4075088/pexels-photo-4075088.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt=""/>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/ShadiMouma/pen/BaKYyYX?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you!! That worked :) I guess my issue was that I set the image to 100 vw and 100vh, but at least as it is 100vw I am happy :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with percentage positioning. For example,

In the parent div

```
position: relative;
```

In the child div

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 30%;
```

Now the child div will always position itself 50% from the top and 30% from the left of the parent div. It does not matter what size the parent div is. I suggest you take a parent div and put the image and texts inside it.

Your example website also uses this technique.
[check their code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMcxU.png)

Another technique would be using HTML canvas. But for something simple like this, HTML canvas would be overkill.

Comment: Hi @ShamsaAnam, this is what I tried but that is not working because the text will only continue to point to the right spot in the image, if the browser is resized in height AND in width. However, if you only resize the width, the image will, for example, get smaller to keep its ratio but then the text will vertically not change as the height was not changed. As a result, the text is no longer pointing to the right spot in the image. Your suggestion only works if I give the image a specific size but it does not work for a fukkscreen image